# Add ShoppingCart Class, and addToCart, itemCount, and isEmpty function in Python

Tags: python, class, cart

I get an assignment, and I am struggling with it. It gives a Transaction Class and its own function already. The task is to add the ShoppingCart Class, and following functions of it: addToCart, removeNextItem, itemCount, isEmpty.

The Transaction Class have already defined/called these to-be-added class and functions, so have to follow these requirements of the Class Transaction.
The closest example can be found at [Python shopping cart add to cart, get total get num items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873523/python-shopping-cart-add-to-cart-get-total-get-num-items), but still there is big difference.

I have tried to added the needed class/functions as below, but I feel it's still far away.

```
class Transaction:

    # Constructor. Takes a shoppingCart upon which it will base the transaction.
    def __init__(self, sc):
        self.shoppingCart = sc


    def getTransactionTotal(self):

        itemList = ""
        totalCost = 0.0


        while not self.shoppingCart.isEmpty():


            itemName, costPerItem, quantity = self.shoppingCart.removeNextItem()

            itemList += (str(quantity) + " × " + str(itemName) + "\n")

            totalCost += (costPerItem * quantity)

        return itemList, totalCost


    def isValidTransaction(self):

        return self.shoppingCart.itemCount() > 0
```

class ShopppingCart

```
class ShoppingCart(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = dict()



    def addToCart(self, name, price, qty):
        if name not in self.content:
            self.content.update({name: (name, price, qty)})
            return
        for k, v in self.content.get(name).items():
            if k == 'qty':
                total_qty = v.qty + qty
                if total_qty:
                    v.qty = total_qty
                    continue
                #self.remove_item(k)
                self.removeNextItem(k)
            else:
                v[k] = item[k]


     #def remove_item(self, key):
    def removeNextItem(self, key):
        self.content.pop(key)

    def itemCount(self):
       for k, v in self.content.get(name).items():
           total_qty = v.qty + qty
        return total_qty

    def isEmpty()
```

Tester function.

```
def main():


    sc = ShoppingCart()

    sc.addToCart("Dijon Ketchup", 4.99, 1)
    sc.addToCart("Van Gogh Doodle", 99.99, 1)
    sc.addToCart("Irregularly Shaped Donut", 0.50, 1)

    sc.addToCart("Poodle", 25.00, 3)
    sc.addToCart("Noodle", 0.99, 10)
    sc.addToCart("Yodel", 2.50, 5)


    trans = Transaction(sc)



    itemizedList, total = trans.getTransactionTotal()


    receipt = "Items\n-------------------\n" + itemizedList
    receipt += "\nTotal Cost: $" + str(total) + "\n\n"


    receipt += "Manually tallied total: $"
    manualTotal = 4.99 + 99.99+ 0.5 + (3 * 25) + (10 * 0.99) + (5 * 2.5)


    receipt += str(manualTotal)

    print(receipt)

    #else:
       # print("Your cart is empty.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: it seems to be right, where is the error exactly?, `def is Empty()` is not a valid function

Comment: itemCount is not right

addToCart: the 5+ onwards line are not sure/not right


 def isEmpty(): not done at all

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: There isn't much of a problem description here. Can you improve this, by editing the question itself? What output do you expect, and what did you get? Would you put those outputs in a formatted block in the question?